# How to change auto generated cs file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have an autogenerated class from entity framework I have changed the type from a string to long in the database along with the name as well thereafter transformed the templates and rebuilt the project however I get an error "The 'Phase' property on 'PropertyDescription' could not be set to a 'Int64' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'String'. "

So it is my thinking that it needs to be changed in the autogenerated cs file somehow but everytime that I change it manually and regenerate the T4 templates it gets over written.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the edits on the fils not egnerated to be OK with the generated files, if you used a variable as string and now you changed and re-generated that variable as a int (or something else), then you have to edit the business linked to this variable is it is needed, there is no refactoring, EF didn't edit the whole project